# WebRTC tunelling through 80/443 tcp

Tags: webrtc, turn

I try to make webRTC app work under corporate firewall that allows only 80 and 443 tcp port, but webRTC use random port(49152-65535). How can i reach?

Comment: Have you talked to your firewall administrators? That seems the first place to start.

Comment: it's not depends on me

Comment: Are you using kurento in any way. I say this because you tagged the question with kurento tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to setup a [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT) server which is capable to handle traffic on TCP 80 and 443 or use a client library which solves this problem by default (such as the mizu webphone).

Comment: Thank you for answer! Can you please show example of TURN server configuration?

Comment: Just setup a turn server such as rfc5766-turn-server and make sure to enable TCP on 80 (and TLS on 443 if you need that also). Then just add this turn server to your webrtc client config and it will detect it automatically (if there is no better way to route the media, such as direct UDP).

Answer (score 0):

You could give [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) a try, it supports TCP transport by default, and if the NAT is very strict and blocks all ports( even outgoing ones) other than 80 and 443, you can set the `listening-port` as 80 and `tls-listening-port` as 443 in the TURN server configuration before starting it.